# Finding the set of size K that contains the most sets

Tags: algorithm

I've run into a problem that has bothered me for quite some time, and I don't really know how to phrase the problem well enough to be able to google the answer to it.

Suppose I have N sets (of, say, integers) and an integer K > 0, how do I find the set of size K that contains the largest number of the N sets?

Ex. I have the sets {1}, {2}, {1,2,3}. For K = 1, one answer would be {1} as it contains 1 of the sets. For K = 2, the answer would be {1,2} as it contains 2 of the sets.

Comment: ties can be broken arbritrarily. I think the interesting thing is finding the max number of the sets that can be covered by a set of size k. How can you do this in O(N)?

Comment: The problem is NP-Complete in general (i.e. it's very difficult and we don't have a super efficient exact solution). It's the Set Cover problem.

Comment: I must be missing something, but I thought the set cover problem involves finding the minimum set to cover the union of all sets. How can that problem be polynomially reduced to this one?

Comment: You are speaking of minimum set cover. To prove NP-completeness you have to turn the problem into a decision problem. For set cover, the decision problem asks "Is there a set cover of size K or less?" You're asking us to find a set of size K that maximally covers all sets. If you could do that in polynomial time (say O(p), you could just increment K until you cover all sets in O(n*p) time, which is still polynomial, thereby solving the set cover problem. Hence, your problem is NP-Complete.

Comment: I understand the statement of the set cover problem as it is stated on most sources (ex Wikipedia). For the set cover decision problem, the size K refers to the number of _sets_ needed to cover the entire "universe" of elements; in my particular problem, the size K refers to the fact that we're taking a subset of the universe. In this sense the two problems are already different: one is taking about a set of sets, the other is just talking about one particular set. Perhaps you can enlighten me as to the decision version of my problem that would reduce to the set covering decision problem?

Comment: And what do you mean by "asking us to find a set of size K that maximally covers all sets". If you're talking about deciding whether there exists a set of size K that covers all of the sets, then that's simple, since the smallest set that does that is the union of  all of the given sets. I don't fully understand what "maximally covers all of the sets" mean.

Comment: I suppose if you're only looking for 1 set of size K, and not a subset of the universe, you could in O(n^2) time compute the amount of overlap between all n sets. Then if you sort the sets into buckets based on length, you could further sort the buckets in terms of overlap, giving lookup time of O(1) after O(n^2 + nlogn) time.

Comment: Does there exist a canonical way to sort sets of the same size "in terms of overlap" that I'm not aware of, especially when overlaps are different depending on the set that you're computing the overlap with? Also, I don't understand how providing an easy way to look up a particular set in the given sets automatically solves the problem. In the example for K=2, the answer {1,2}, does not equal any of the given sets : {1}, {2}, {1,2,3}.

Answer (score 0):

Given a set N of a set of numbers, find the set K of integers, size `k`, such that the maximum number of members of N are subsets of K.

The worst possible way would be to consider the [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of N (that is, the set of all possible subsets), call it P.  For each member of P, take the union of all its members and see if it is size `k`.

That algorithm would be O(2^n). There is probably a way to improve on it.